# Isomorphism of group algebras $k[G\times H]\cong k[G]\otimes k[H]$ and interpretation

Tags: abstract-algebra

could someone check it the following is correct? I want to show the isomorphism of $k$-modules ($k$ a Ring) as mentioned in the title. I would like to simplyfy the situation to two finite groups $G=\{g_1,g_2\}, H=\{h_1, h_2\}$ and denote the base of the group algebras $k[G], k[H]$ $\delta g_1,\delta g_2$ and $\delta h_1, \delta h_2$ respectively.

Define a map $f:k[G]\times k[H] \to k[G\times H]$ via $(\delta_g,\delta_h)\mapsto \delta_{(g,h)}$ and extend bilinearly. This map clearly descends to a map $\tilde f:k[G]\otimes k[H]\mapsto k[G\times H]$ where $\delta_g\otimes \delta_h$ gets mapped to $\delta_{(g,h)}$. This map is a $k-linear$ Map and it's inverse is obvious. So $k[G]\otimes k[H]\cong k[G\times H]$ as $k$-modules.

Is this proof ok?

The thing that surprises me is the following: I can look at say $k_1\delta_{g_1}\otimes \delta_{h_1}+k_2\delta_{g_2}\otimes \delta_{h_1}=k_1\delta_{g_1}+k_2\delta_{g_2}\otimes \delta_{h_1}$, where the left Hand side corresponds to $k_1 \delta_{(g_1,h_1)}+k_2\delta_{(g_2,h_1)}$, but the right Hand side has no correspondence in $k[G\times H]$ in the sense of "summarizing" Base Elements as in the tensor product. There I think a can proof the isomorphism of modules, but I cannot really See it.

Can anybody understand my misunderstanding an help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is ok to show that they are isomorphic as $k$-vector spaces, but you have to add another arguent to show that they are isomorphic as $k$-algebras.

You can just check that on the basis elements you chose.

Another way to see that they are isomorphic  is to check that they satisfy the same universal property.

Then $A:= k[G\times H]$ satisfies that for any $k$-algebra $C$, $$Hom_{k-alg}(A,C) = Hom_{grp}(G\times H,C^*) = Hom_{grp}(G,C^*)\times Hom_{grp}(H,C^*).$$

And $B:= k[G]\otimes_k k[H]$ satisfies that 
$$Hom_{k-alg}(B,C) = Hom_{k-alg}(k[G],C)\times Hom_{k-alg}(k[H],C) = Hom_{grp}(G,C^*)\times Hom_{grp}(H,C^*).$$

So indeed they are canonically isomorphic.

---

I don't understand your issue with $k_1\delta_{g_1}\otimes \delta_{h_1}+k_2\delta_{g_2}\otimes \delta_{h_1}=(k_1\delta_{g_1}+k_2\delta_{g_2})\otimes \delta_{h_1}$. It does correspond to $k_1 \delta_{(g_1,h_1)}+k_2\delta_{(g_2,h_1)}$, what more would you want to ask ?

You seem to think that the fact that it is a pure tensor in $k[G]\otimes_k k[H]$ should imply a special form in $k[G\times H]$. But pure tensors are pretty complicated in general : for instance in the isomorphism $End(V)\simeq V\otimes V^*$, pure tensors correspond to rank $1$ matrices, which don't have a simple form.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks on the proof and the Alternative Version. And yes, "You seem to think that the fact that it is a pure tensor in $k[G]\otimes_k k[H]$ should imply a special form in $k[G\times H]$" that's exactly it! For example it holds that $k[x,y]\cong k[x]\otimes k[y]$. Here $(x+x^2)\otimes y=x\otimes y+x^2\otimes y$ has a nice correspondence in $k[x,y]$ as $(x+x^2)y=xy+x^2y$. This does not apply for the group algebras as $(\delta  g_1 + \delta g_2)h_1$ is not even a proper expression in $k[G\times H]$.